# Method not found GetJsonAsync while using Flurl

Tags: c#, flurl

I am trying to call api using Flurl and here is my request which only fails on my testserver but works on live server and localhost as well

```
PickUp responseAsPickUpPointServiceResponse = null;
        try
        {
            responseAsPickUpPointServiceResponse =
                await new Flurl.Url(_baseUrl + "/rest//v1/servicepoint/findByPostalCode.json")
                    .SetQueryParam("apikey", APIKEY_WEB1)
                    .SetQueryParam("countryCode", countrycode)
                    .SetQueryParam("postalCode", zipcode)
                    .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                    .GetJsonAsync<PickUp>();
        }
```

BUt it fails with error

**Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Flurl.Http.GeneratedExtensions.GetJsonAsync(Flurl.Http.IFlurlRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption)**

Has anyone idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you figure out how to resolve this?

Comment: @jorgeAChacon no unfortunately

Comment: I have to do iisreset after every time I build the application...

Answer (score 1):

Same here, I got the same error `Method not found [...] GetJsonAsync` when running my *integration tests* although it was working well with *unit tests*.

In my case, there were two projects where `Flurl.Http` versions mismatched :

`main.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="3.0.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="..\other\imported.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`imported.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="2.8.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="2.4.2" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The error was fixed by bumping *Flurl* version to `3.0.1` everywhere :

In both files :

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="3.0.1" />
```